# Cisco AnyConnect on two seperate Cisco ASA

Tags: vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I have two Cisco ASA 5508-X devices, one is production and is currently running Cisco AnyConnect VPN which we have a license for 100 concurrent connections. The other is a hot spare. The device has a hardware limit of only  100 concurrent connections, which was fine until this Corona Virus pandemic. We have a little over 150 employees. We are considering buying another license for the rest of our users. Is it possible to run AnyConnect on both of these ASA's simultaneously to allow all of my users access or is this a dream request? I cannot find any documentation or forum anywhere on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can and there are a couple of ways to do it. There may be licensing implications. Clustering and Load Balancing. The best way I've found is ASA load balancing. Both units are active, one becomes the master and accepts all the incoming connection requests, but it decides based on load which server to send the user to. There are some implications regarding certificates, pools (must be unique on each server, so pools may need to be split) and other small things based on your architecture.

Clustering:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa98/configuration/general/asa-98-general-config/ha-cluster.html

Load Balancing:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa99/configuration/vpn/asa-99-vpn-config/vpn-ha.html#ID-2186-000003f2